# Matlab - How to delete only contents from folder

Tags: matlab

I wanted to know how it is possible to delete only the contents (files and folders) of a specific folder, without deleting this folder. Delete only child folders.
I have tried this, but this will delete the folder too:

```
rmdir(listFolders,'s')
```

Comment: What's wrong with rmdir followed by a mkdir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function work fine:

```
function rmSubDir( pathDir )

    d = dir(pathDir);
    isub = [d(:).isdir];
    nameFolds = {d(isub).name}';
    nameFolds(ismember(nameFolds,{'.','..'})) = [];

     for i=1:size(nameFolds,1)
        dir2rm = fullfile(pathDir,nameFolds{i});
        rmdir(dir2rm, 's');
     end

end
```